# using user interface, nearpoint/renderprint/verbatimTextOutput('print') to show part of variables on user click

Tags: html, r, user-interface, shiny

Below I attach the code I use for the Shiny application. I am wondering how I can specifically use click="plot_click"/near-point/render print, to show part of data(). If you look at the attached image, you see that bunch of info has appeared [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EyK3.png), but I need to take "name", and winning times only.

```
 #code------------------------------------  
 server<- function(input, output, session) {

  #wrangling data:
 gslam<- as.data.frame(gslam1)
  gslam$tournament <- sapply(gslam$tournament, function(val) 
  {agrep(val, c('Australian Open', 'U.S. 
   Open','Wimbledon','FrenchOpen'), 
                                                               
  value = TRUE)})

  #pivot plot based on Tournament
  reactive_data<-reactive({
  req(input$sel_tournament)
  df<- gslam %>% filter(tournament %in% 
  input$sel_tournament)%>%group_by(winner,tournament)%>% 
   mutate(winningNumber=n())
  df<-df %>% arrange(winner)
  })

 #dynamic list

  observe({
updateSelectInput(session,"sel_tournament", choices = 
 gslam$tournament, select="U.S. Open")
   })



    # create the plot  
  output$WinnerPlot <- renderPlot({

  g<- ggplot(reactive_data(),aes( y =winner,  x 
 =winningNumber),decreasing=FALSE) + 
  theme(legend.position=none")
```

g+geom_bar(stat="identity",width=0.5, fill="black")})

output$print = renderPrint({
nearPoints(
reactive_data(),             # the plotting data
input$plot_click,   # input variable to get the x/y
maxpoints = 1,      # only show the single nearest point
threshold = 1000    # basically a search radius. set this big

```
                      # to show at least one point per click
    )})

 output$Top5Plot <-renderPlot({
g<- ggplot(reactive_data(),aes( y =winner,  x 
=winningNumber),decreasing=FALSE) + theme(legend.position = 
"none")

    g+geom_bar(stat="identity",width=0.5, fill="black")

  })

}

ui <- navbarPage("Grand Slam Shiny Application", id="cc",
             tabPanel("Winners' Rank",
                      fluidRow(titlePanel("Grand Slam 
ShinyApp"),
                                 sidebarPanel(
                                   selectInput(inputId = 
"sel_tournament",label="Choose Tournament:","Names"))), 
plotOutput(("WinnerPlot"), click="plot_click"),
                 verbatimTextOutput('print')
                                                ),
             
             tabPanel("Top 5 Winners' Performance", 
plotOutput("Top5Plot"))
             )

# Run the App
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may take help of `dplyr::select` in `nearPoints`.

```
output$print = renderPrint({
  nearPoints(
    dplyr::select(reactive_data(), winner, winningNumber),      
    input$plot_click,   
    maxpoints = 1,      
    threshold = 1000  
  )})
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I've tested but it doesn't change the output, still all information output as I do click.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately, I can't test this because you have not shared the data to reproduce the issue.